# VueJS beforeRouteEnter hook not firing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to follow the instructions laid out here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#adding-custom-hooks

I'm not getting any errors, but `beforeRouteEnter` fails to fire. I'm not seeing either of the console output lines.

Oddly, if I insert a `beforeEnter` on my router, `hello` will print, but not `hi`.

Example code below.

class-component-hooks.ts

```
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

// Register the router hooks with their names
Component.registerHooks([
  'beforeRouteEnter',
  'beforeRouteLeave',
  'beforeRouteUpdate', // for vue-router 2.2+
]);
```

main.ts

```
import './class-component-hooks';

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
...
```

some_component.ts

```
import { Component, Watch, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component({
  ...
  beforeRouteEnter(to: any, from: any, next: (arg0: (vm: any) => void) => void) {
    console.log('hello');
    next((vm) => {
      // access to component instance via `vm`
      console.log('hi');
    });
  }
})
...
```

Scenario where it partially fires:

router.ts

```
{
   path: '/a_route',
   component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "a_route" */ './a_route.vue'),
   beforeEnter: (to: any, from: any, next: (arg0: (vm: any) => void) => void) => {
      console.log('hello');
      next((vm) => {
         // access to component instance via `vm`
         console.log('hi');
      });
   },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did everything correctly, you've registered hooks and you've imported them before the component definitions but your component class hasn't inherited from `Vue`.

```
@Component({
  ...
  beforeRouteEnter(to: any, from: any, next: (arg0: (vm: any) => void) => void) {
    console.log('hello');
    next((vm) => {
      // access to component instance via `vm`
      console.log('hi');
    });
  }
})
```

Try this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

@Component
class MyComp extends Vue {
      ...
      beforeRouteEnter(to: any, from: any, next: (arg0: (vm: any) => void) => void) {
        console.log('hello');
        next((vm) => {
          // access to component instance via `vm`
          console.log('hi');
        });
      }
}
```